# How to implement jboss transaction in Kie Piesistence?

Tags: jboss, drools, kie

I am trying to implement kiePersistence in my rule engine. I am able to implement transactions using `bitronix` DataSourcePooling. As mentioned in the Drools documentation it is not suitable to use in production. Can anyone help me with an example of JBoss transaction management?

Answer (score 0):

Please specify the following property in your persistence.xml to enable jBOSS transaction management for your kie-server.

```
<property name="hibernate.transaction.jta.platform"
                value="org.hibernate.service.jta.platform.internal.JBossAppServerJtaPlatform" />
```

Comment: how can i define `jta source` programettically?

Comment: when i am using `bitronix transaction management` i am creating a DataSourcePool of bitronix but for JBoss I am not finding any DataSourcePool. If you have any example or reference URL please provide it will be very helpful for me.